# Is there a way to FilterasUtype using a textbox in Access

Tags: ms-access, filtering

I have a subform bound to a table "dbo_IN_Master" which includes field "strDescription". The customer requires a textbox on the main form that will filter the table by the values as she types in the textbox txtSearchDesc:

1. She keys and filters for 1st word (table filtering as she goes)
2. then, a space and she keeps typing characters contained in the field to continue filtering
3. Sometimes, another space and more characters contained in the field.

Basically, I am wanting a drill down feature for the form.
Her current database accomplishes this; however, it is obsolete and unknown and source code is unavailable.

Here is the exact code I am using. No filtering happens when I key anything in txtSearchDesc and when I clear the field I get error 9.

```
Function BuildFilter(strF As String, strS As String)
Dim aryS As Variant, strN As String, x As Integer
aryS = Split(strS, " ")
strN = strF & " LIKE '" & Replace(aryS(0), "'", "''") & "*' AND "
For x = 1 To UBound(aryS)
    strN = strN & strF & " LIKE '*" & Replace(aryS(x), "'", "''") & "*' AND "
Next
BuildFilter = Left(strN, Len(strN) - 5)
End Function
Private Sub txtSearchDesc_Change()
'strDescription is the name of the field in the table I am filtering
Me.Filter = BuildFilter("[strDescription]", Me.txtSearchDesc.Text)
End Sub
```

Here is what finally worked for me:

```
    Private Sub txtSearchDesc_Change()
    Dim strCondition As String
    strCondition = Replace(Me.txtSearchDesc.Text, "#", "[#]") ' deal with fact that # is a special character in SQL
    strCondition = "strDescription like '*" & Join(Split(strCondition, " "), "*' and strDescription like '*") & "*'" ' create required filter
    Me.sfrm_Search.Form.Filter = strCondition
    Me.sfrm_Search.Form.FilterOn = True ' make sure filter is activated
If Me.txtSearchDesc = "" Then
Me.sfrm_Search.Form.FilterOn = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppFindAsUType.html

Comment: Code needs to parse textbox input to separate word elements and use each as search criteria with wildcard pattern matching and/or InStr() function. Parsing can be done with Split() function to an array then reference array to build search phrase https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function. As you can see, what you want is complicated and doubt will find canned code to fully suit. Have to modify.

Comment: Thanks, June7. I did look at that Allen Browne code and it was too advanced for me. There is an easier one on Tek-Tips I am trying to get to work. It almost does what I want.

Comment: Thanks, Kostas, for the edit. Can you point me to a solution? I found code for a combobox that filters itself as you type but not the form. But I need a textbox to filter the records on the form in that way.

Comment: Instead of applying filter criteria to combobox, apply it to form. MIght want to use textbox for input instead of combobox. If you have code, then edit your question to show it.

Comment: Thanks, June7. I have code which filters a combo box AsUType. Not what I need. Customer wants a textbox on a form which filters the form records as you type. My rudimentary VBA/SQL skills don't cover that and Filter As You Type for a textbox on a form, apparently, is not very popular. Sorry if I was vague. Jana

Comment: I suggest you use the `Sub FilterFunc` code from link referenced in my answer (you had that code posted before) along with my suggested function as instructed in my answer. It has an `If Then Else` block that handles condition when control is empty.

Comment: I did try that but it didn't work. That's why I moved on to try your other suggestions. So far, I'm having no luck. Apologies for being so dense. I am not much of a programmer anyway, but this has me completely in the dark. Also, I didn't notice I had to click "More Comments" to see more comments. I missed yours.

Comment: Don't know what else to say. Code works for me. I used procedure from second link in my answer. I only had to change the one line setting Filter property to reference my function.

Comment: Well, thanks so much for your time and efforts! I have to keep working on this and get it done. If I get anything working,, glad to give you the credit.

Comment: You could post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Need code that sets either form RecordSource or form Filter property. Dynamically filtering form with VBA is a common topic and doesn't really matter what controls are used, basic code is the same. However, find-as-you-type does call for a variation using combobox or textbox OnChange event and Text property.  Following are two links for examples to set Filter property using textbox as-you-type input:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64447061/vba-search-using-text-box-in-access#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20search%20%28filter%29%20as%20you,FilterOn%20%3D%20True%20End%20If%20End%20Sub%20Share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64447061/vba-search-using-text-box-in-access#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20search%20%28filter%29%20as%20you,FilterOn%20%3D%20True%20End%20If%20End%20Sub%20Share)
and
https://ss64.com/access/syntax-filter.html

For your specific requirement of multiple parameters, consider this helper function to build criteria:

```
Function BuildFilter(strF As String, strS As String)
Dim aryS As Variant, strN As String, x As Integer
aryS = Split(strS, " ")
strN = strF & " LIKE '" & Replace(aryS(0), "'", "''") & "*' AND "
For x = 1 To UBound(aryS)
    strN = strN & strF & " LIKE '*" & Replace(aryS(x), "'", "''") & "*' AND "
Next
BuildFilter = Left(strN, Len(strN) - 5)
End Function
```

That code will search for value that starts with the first word typed. If you want to find match where ANY word typed is found ANYwhere in value, consider:

```
Function BuildFilter(strF As String, strS As String)
Dim aryS As Variant, strN As String, x As Integer
aryS = Split(strS, " ")
For x = 0 To UBound(aryS)
    strN = strN & strF & " LIKE '*" & Replace(aryS(x), "'", "''") & "*' AND "
Next
BuildFilter = Left(strN, Len(strN) - 5)
End Function
```

Call function from whatever procedure sets the form's Filter property (I used code from second link above). Arguments are for field name and textbox content. Reference directly by name or variables:

```
Me.Filter = BuildFilter("[Description]", Me.textboxname.Text)
```

or

```
Me.Filter = BuildFilter(strField, Me(strControl).Text)
```

Comment: June7 Thank you! I was able to use the shortened Allen Browne code link above. It works almost exactly the way I want. I appreciate your help in my struggle. My old brain is giving out :)

Comment: Upon more rigorous testing, I noticed that the search textbox does not filter on the first keyed in letter, then the second, etc. I can type in a word and it does filter on descriptions containing that word but customer insists on filter as you type. Ex: Looking for Face Shield Cover, does not filter to Beginning with Face til I get to "FACE SH". Sorry about the delay but I am still trying to figure it out.

Comment: I tested code from second link along with my suggested function and it works for me. Starts filtering with first letter typed. If you need more help, then need to post your actual code. Edit your question.

Comment: Question edited. Code posted.

Comment: Your posted code is not using the function I suggested. Did you try it? Posted code should begin filter with first character typed. Again, works for me.

Comment: Revised to deal with apostrophes in data. No issue with # and quote marks.

Comment: Question edited again. Your code exactly as I am using it posted.