# How can I filter a listbox on a form using multiple values in a textbox?

Tags: ms-access, filter, textbox, listbox

I am most likely doing this all wrong and there is another way I need to do this. I am new with Access as my job ended up depending on it to continue to operate the same for our customers. I was given the role of subject matter expert because I watched a few YouTube videos and googled a few things.

I am trying to filter a list of assigned worked based on values I get from a SharePoint entry. These values are separated by different delimiters (comma, carriage return, semicolon, etc.). After manipulation I need to be able to have the listbox filtered to these multiple values.

I have a query set up with the assignment id as the criteria pointing to a textbox on the form.

The criteria in the query is:
[Forms]![MyForm]![txtIdSearch]

I’ve had the criteria that is passed into the query to include and exclude quotation marks, e.g *“123” OR “456” OR “789”* and *123 OR 456 OR 789*, the “[MyTable].[ColumnName] =“ between each ID with and without quotes, e.g. *“123” OR [MyTable].[ColumnName] = “456” OR [MyTable].[ColumnName] = “789”* and *[MyTable].[ColumnName] = 123 OR [MyTable].[ColumnName] = 456 OR [MyTable].[ColumnName] = 789*.

Any assistance is much appreciated and thank you in advance. Please let me know if there is more information needed to help.

Each of these options have provided no results. If only one value is in the textbox with no quotes it will pull that item. But no matter the syntax I use I am not able to get more than one result at a time.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75583419/is-there-a-way-to-filterasutype-using-a-textbox-in-access/75608232#75608232

Comment: Edit question to show sample data as formatted text table. Exactly what is typed into textbox?